# Scaling/Units of power spectrum (with R)

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft, spectrum, spectrogram

The `spec.pgram()` or the equivalent `spectrum()` functions in R scale the spectrum accroding to the documentation as follows:

> The spectrum here is defined with scaling 1/frequency(x), following
>   S-PLUS. This makes the spectral density a density over the range
>   (-frequency(x)/2, +frequency(x)/2]

```
spectrum(sin(seq(0, 10, 0.1)))
```

[image]

Given a signal recorded for 100 ms with a sampling rate of 1000 Hz, what would be the correct scaling of the axis?

Comment: The X-axis represents the frequency (expressed as a fraction of the sampling rate. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. There were 2 things which confused me: The fact, that one takes only half of the sampling rate and then that the sampling interval has no influence on the scaling. This was not obvious for me as a beginner in signal processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of the axis is [-Fs/2, Fs/2]. For the example you have with a sampling rate of 1000 Hz, the x axis would be -500 Hz to 500 Hz.